# Mimic Active Record Relation Render Behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I would like to mimic the rendering behavior of `ActiveRecord::Relation` in my own class. Specifically, when you instantiate an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, it doesn't actually execute the underlying query until it is being rendered:

```
<%= my_relation %>
```

I thought maybe Rails calls `my_relation.inspect`, to execute the query, but that method doesn't return all of the data.

What method(s) would I need to define for my custom class so the underlying calculations are not executed until necessary?

Comment: FYI, the query is executed when it is needed, not when rendered. If you do `users = User.where(id: User.where(id: 1..999))`, the query with `id: 1..999` is executed because it is needed to "compute" the outer query. Also, doing a simple `User.where(...).to_a` triggers the execution of the query.

Comment: So what method is being called when it is rendered? Is ERB calling .load on any ActiveRecord::Relation object?

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

I think you want to define/override `#each` OR delegate `#each`.
However, you could also make use of defining/overriding `#to_s`.

#### Details

```
<%= my_relation %>
```

I don't think your example will do much of anything related to ActiveRecord::Relation loading records. The ERb will convert the `my_relation` object to a string (`#to_s`) which will not load the records.

Note that in this case you could override the `#to_s` method (or delegate it) so that it performs any action you like on an object.

I think you were probably referring to something like:

```
<%= render my_relation %>
```

Without digging into too much code I would suspect that `#each` is being invoked on `my_relation`.

An `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance delegates `#each` to `:records`. ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5fd50c387bdfc2761859ec7a57477bcd56e93210/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L41-L44))

Further more we can see that `#records` in turn calls `#load`. ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5fd50c387bdfc2761859ec7a57477bcd56e93210/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L251))

You can follow this pattern, using `#each` to perform actions lazily or on-demand.